# Netflix in Silverlight missing the HD option on one PC

Tags: windows-7, silverlight, netflix

This is Netflix on my laptop:

[image]

This is Netflix on my desktop PC:

[image]

Eagle-eyed viewers will notice that the HD button is missing from the latter, and the quality is poor.

Actually, it does improve a little with time but never plays HD.

This occurs in all browsers using the **Silverlight** player, so **IE and Firefox**. Therefore you would think it nothing to do with cookies etc, and maybe something to do with Silverlight-centric data.

In **Chrome**, which uses their HTML5 player, there is also no HD button, but that's a change in said HTML5 version. In a moment, you will see it can do HD.

In each context, you can access a hidden menu that gives you (1) streaming info and (2) A/V stats.

These are the streaming details.

Laptop (HD, 3000kbps available):

[image: Laptop HD]

PC (not HD, limited to 1750):

[image: PC SD]

Chrome on PC, HTML5 (HD, 3000 available):

[image: Chrome]

Everything in the A/V stats, apart from the graphics card info, is pretty much the same between laptop and PC.

Everything else I can think of is also the same; DNS, actual network speed, OS version (W7 x64). Even the screen resolution.

I've uninstalled Silverlight using the MS iFixit tool, and reinstalled it. Twice.

Netflix Support have been useless; I was using a DNS service (on both machines!) so as soon as it gets more technical than 'try another browser', they blame that.

Any ideas? What can I try meddling with? Even experiments to try.

As requested, the machines are:

- **PC**: AMD X4 955, 16GB RAM, GTX 970, 1920x1200 monitor over DVI, Win7 x64
- **Laptop**: Dell Latitude E650, i7-4800MQ, 8GB RAM, 1920x1080, Win7 x64
- **Another desktop that works fine**: AMD X2 5200, GT 220, 4GB RAM, output to an HDTV over HDMI, Win10 Tech Preview 32-bit

This is the HDCP Status on the other desktop I have, connected to a TV & working in HD as mentioned, just in case you think Netflix require it or something:

[image]

Comment: AMD X4 955, 16GB RAM, GTX970, a monitor running at 1920x1200.

Comment: Done, although to be frank, I'm sceptical that the actual hardware has much to do with it.

Comment: Your PC is connected to the monitor over a digital cable correct?  HDMI, DisplayPort, what exactly?  Same version of IE?  If I didn't think it was important I wouldn't have asked for that information.  Are you able to watch HD videos on YouTube by chance?  How is the PC connected to your internet compared to your laptop?

Comment: Yes, YouTube HD works fine, as does any local HD playback. The PC is wired LAN over Homeplug (as is the Win10 PC), the laptop is Wi-Fi. Network performance is good, 20ms ping and about 17Mbps download measured on this PC. Same browser versions on all machines. Display info added to the question. Neither the TV nor the PC monitor support HDCP, should that come up.

Comment: Just in case, I tried HDMI out of the graphics card, then adapted to DVI-D, instead of DVI-D directly. Same result.

Comment: That is the problem.  You need to use at the very least an HDMI cable on the PC.  Your other desktop has a secure connection clearly your TV does support HDCP since its working.  Since you updated the comment, the adapter, would be the problem.

Comment: This is from the HDTV PC where Netflix works in HD: http://wapoc.com/netflix/nf-hdcp.png . Excuse the poor colour depth, it was accessed remotely. I can connect the PC to the TV if I absolutely have to to test this, but not with any ease.

Comment: It would help.  At the end of the day Silverlight player is the reason your having these problems.

Comment: If this is the case, then noone anywhere can use Netflix HD on a monitor that only has physical DVI connectors - i.e. most PC monitors I've ever seen. Surely not!